# Regex Php Url Protocol

Tags: php, regex

Hy guys can you help me with this, a Regular Expression syntax to do the following

1. if a link starts with // then i will make a string concatenation to add 
   "file:"
2. if a link starts with nothing i will make a string concatenation to add 
   "html://"

example for 1 if it starts with
 //host/data/user/temp/data.text want to make it "file://host/data/user..."

example:for 2 if it starts with 
 Google.com i want to make it "html://Google.com"

Comment: `file:` scheme requires one more `/` and `html:` is not a scheme that's well supported. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Try this.   
     $subject =   'filename';
     //$subject =  '//filename';
    if(preg_match("/^\/\//", $subject)){
      //$newstring=  preg_replace("/^\/\//", "file://", $subject);
      $newstring= "file:".$subject;
    }else{
     $newstring= "http://".$subject;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful but i think i asked the wrong questions do you know how can i make it so it can detect on what path to go, to only have a single $subject variable and treat it with and "if"

Comment: as jack suggested i am not very clear about what you requirement. Post it as a new question and if you find this useful. please up vote.. badly need some reputation:)

Comment: It would be `$newstring = "file:" . $subject;`, the // is already there, and also `strpos()` would be more efficient.

Comment: i am sorry.. corrected the answer.. but not sure that was downvoted?